# SQL OPENJSON get only first element

Tags: sql, arrays, json

I'm trying to get data from only the first element in the JSON string because the first element will always be the newest. I have tried a few things with no luck. Maybe someone here can point me in the right direction.

This is the JSON string:

```
[
{
    "wd:Transaction_Log_Entry": [
        {
            "wd:Transaction_Log_Reference": {
                "@wd:Descriptor": "Rescind of End Contract: XXXX (Rescinded)",
                "wd:ID": {
                    "@wd:type": "WID",
                    "#text": "fb27bafef89b101b5bf865947b420000"
                }
            },
            "wd:Transaction_Log_Data": {
                "wd:Transaction_Log_Description": "Rescind of End Contract: XXXX (Rescinded)",
                "wd:Transaction_Effective_Moment": "2023-01-18T09:00:00+01:00",
                "wd:Transaction_Entry_Moment": "2023-01-19T10:49:00.868+01:00",
                "wd:Is_Rescind_Or_Rescinded": "1",
                "wd:Is_Correction_Or_Corrected": "0"
            }
        },
        {
            "wd:Transaction_Log_Reference": {
                "@wd:Descriptor": "End Contract: XXXX (Rescinded)",
                "wd:ID": {
                    "@wd:type": "WID",
                    "#text": "a4a0fd2c2df8101bd1c6bde5f5710000"
                }
            },
            "wd:Transaction_Log_Data": {
                "wd:Transaction_Log_Description": "End Contract: XXXX (Rescinded)",
                "wd:Transaction_Effective_Moment": "2023-01-18T09:00:00+01:00",
                "wd:Transaction_Entry_Moment": "2023-01-18T12:41:43.867+01:00",
                "wd:Is_Rescind_Or_Rescinded": "1",
                "wd:Is_Correction_Or_Corrected": "0"
            }
        }
    ]
}
]
```

And my SQL query - I'm selecting the JSON string from a table that has the column name 'Transaction_Log_Entry_Data'

```
 SELECT Effective_Moment, Entry_Moment  
 FROM [dbo].[Daily_And_Future_Terminations_Transaction_Log_Source] 
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Transaction_Log_Entry_Data, '$[0]."wd:Transaction_Log_Entry"')
 WITH (
        Effective_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Effective_Moment"',
        Entry_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Entry_Moment"'
       )
```

And my results is 2 rows and I only want data from the first element:

[image]

Best regards
Ole

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1):

You have an arry in an array, so you must write.

JSOn is an interesting data structure, but you need a lot of experience with it

```
 SELECT Effective_Moment, Entry_Moment  
 FROM [Daily_And_Future_Terminations_Transaction_Log_Source] 
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Transaction_Log_Entry_Data, '$[0]."wd:Transaction_Log_Entry"[0]')
 WITH (
        Effective_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Effective_Moment"',
        Entry_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Entry_Moment"'
       )
```

| Effective_Moment | Entry_Moment |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-18T09:00:00+01:00 | 2023-01-19T10:49:00.868+01:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rh2XD4Zn)

```
 SELECT TOP 1 Effective_Moment, Entry_Moment  
 FROM [Daily_And_Future_Terminations_Transaction_Log_Source] 
 CROSS APPLY OPENJSON (Transaction_Log_Entry_Data, '$[0]."wd:Transaction_Log_Entry"')
 WITH (
        Effective_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Effective_Moment"',
        Entry_Moment NVARCHAR(50) '$."wd:Transaction_Log_Data"."wd:Transaction_Entry_Moment"'
       )
ORDEr By Entry_Moment DESC
```

| Effective_Moment | Entry_Moment |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-01-18T09:00:00+01:00 | 2023-01-19T10:49:00.868+01:00 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Jc2CAox2)

Comment: I just see it now :) It is of course the first element in the arry. my focus was elsewhere. The backup I had was just to use Select top(1) which does work, but it's more elegant the other way. I also looked into get the MAX value for the Entry Moment and thereby not relying on the order of the elements - Thx nbk

Comment: if you want the oldest enty Zop still works but only with the correct order see second example